# htaccess mod_rewrite URL problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to re-write this url here;

```
site.com/product.php?s=electricity-at-work-regulations
```

to

```
site.com/courses/electricity-at-work-regulations
```

so change product.php to courses and generally tidy the url up.

Is this possible?

**.htacess file**

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^peoplefactor.co.uk$ [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://peoplefactor.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>


   # Clean URLS
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       Options -MultiViews
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/preview$ /blog/post.php?s=$1&preview=all [L]
       RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]

       RewriteRule ^course/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /course.php?s=$1 [L]

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
     </IfModule>

      # Gets rid of www.
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On


        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it would be better the other way around.
You should always call site.com/courses/electricity-at-work-regulations within your application and reroute it to site.com/product.php?s=electricity-at-work-regulations. Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(courses)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$  product.php?s=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

As you've suggested, I'll change it in the application to 'courses'. Would you happen to know the best way to clean up this url?

`site.com/courses.php?s=electricity-at-work-regulations`

to read

`site.com/courses/electricity-at-work-regulations`

Thanks again.

Comment: From the top of my head, should look like RewriteRule ^(courses.php\?s\=)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$  courses/$2 [L]  can't test it tho

Comment: This seemed to work for me,
`RewriteRule ^course/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /course.php?s=$1 [L]` but now none of my css or js files are working. It's strange because when i view source the links are there and no errors in the developer tools. Any ideas?

Comment: add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f before the rule

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, if i add that before, it throws up a internal server message.

I've got that line in from a previous rewrite, could it be conflicting?

Comment: Thought it might be easier if i added my mod_rewrite code for you to see.

Comment: Condition only works for the following rule. You might need to duplicate